# Is it yet possible to use Facebook video chat without a VM?

Tags: wine, facebook

I use Xubuntu actually, and I have Wine, if that helps.

I installed FacebookVideoCallSetup_v1.2.199.0.exe after going to 
http://www.facebook.com/videocalling
by using wine like this:

```
wine FacebookVideoCallSetup_v1.2.199.0.exe
```

Is my only option to try Facebook via a browser that is running in Wine?

Comment: Good question - the linux community is very ingenious when it comes to this sort of challenge.  Give it a short while - I'm sure a solution will turn up soon.

Comment: how did you installed via wine
I have tried everything and there is no way to get it to work

Comment: @msramalho it was a long time ago, I wouldn't recommend it: perhaps just run VirtualBox with Windows 7 or 8 etc, with Skype or Firefox on it if you have to. Skype and Facebook are spyware anyway. Consider Jitsi, RedPhone etc.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately it seems that you can only do it that way, even when the deeper information gives a clue on which browsers you can use, it also gives null expectations about its usage under linux, as we can read in: http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=211644178877843

> Which browser should I use to set up
>   video calling?
>   == Video calling works best with the latest versions of the following
>   browsers:
>
> Mozilla Firefox
>
> Google Chrome
>
> Internet Explorer
>
> Safari
>
> ***Note that video calling for Linux is not currently supported. You will
>   need to use one of these browsers in a
>   Mac or Windows operating system. If
>   you’re having trouble with video
>   calling, try upgrading or switching
>   your browser using the links above.***

Nevertheless, the sentence that reads "is not currently supported" gives a hope that they will work on such a support for linux users, so let's wait patiently for it.

Anyway, in my personal experience using internet explorer under wine, I didn't get native results as in a MS based system, so you may experience some issues when trying to use this feature.